# How to filter MotionEvent.getAction() on API level 3 (no ACTION_MASK present)

Tags: android

Im writing an `OnTouchListener`. I found out that I can check for the ActionType by using bit-operations like

```java
if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
```

however `MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK` is not present in Android 1.5 (API level 3)
How is/was it done there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ACTION_MASK` is used to separate the actual action and the pointer identifier (e.g. first finger touched, second finger touched, etc.) The first 8 bits of the value returned in [getAction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getAction%28%29) is the actual action part, and so when you bitwise-AND it with the [action mask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_MASK) (= 11111111 = 255 = 0xff), you are left with only the action and none of the pointer information.

In Android 1.5 / API level 3, we did not have support in the `MotionEvent` class for multiple pointers (i.e. multitouch). For a single pointer event, the pointer bits are not set. You can therefore just compare the event with the desired action constant to obtain the check for the particular action:

```
if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {...}
```

In the unlikely event that this does not work, you can try to define your own action mask constant to be 255 and bitwise-AND it with the action as in later API versions.

On the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) for `MotionEvent` (or indeed any Android reference page), there is a checkbox to filter by API level. If you select API level 3, you can see the state of that class at the time. All of the methods and constants related to the different pointers are greyed out.

Comment: Thank your very much for your time and answer. Im still wondering though because this expression would resolve to false on newer android versions. Will this *just work* on any device/level from 3 to now? If yes, is it because of the target/min_sdk information I entered on project creation?

Comment: The expression is always valid for single pointer touch events, even for later API levels. For a single pointer, the other (pointer) bits are not set so there is no need for the mask.